# CSS Working Different in Chrome and IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have this CSS class that is working fine in Chrome, but in IE 8(yes my work still uses IE 8) the background image isn't showing up.  I am thinking that IE 8 may not know what to do with some part of the CSS but haven't been able to pin point it.

Here is the CSS class

```
ul.action:not(.btnImage) li a:not(.btnImage), ul.groupAction:not(.btnImage) li a:not(.btnImage),  ul.actionGradient:not(.btnImage) li a:not(.btnImage){
background-color: transparent !important;
background: url("../images/buttons/btnShineBackground.png") top left repeat-x !important;
border-width: 0px 1px !important;
border-color: #f47a2a !important;
border-style: ridge !important;
padding: 0px !important;
color: #FFF !important;
width: 120px !important;
height: 29px !important;
text-align: center !important;
vertical-align: middle !important;
line-height: 29px !important;
font-size: 10px !important;
font-weight: lighter !important;
font-family: Arial Black !important;
font-style: normal !important;
text-transform: uppercase !important;
```

And here is the HTML

```
<ul class=" action"><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousemove="window.status='';"     onmouseout="window.status='';" id="r898BB6A34E694110894F489DA4BEA3BB1DE_3" onfocus="storeFocusField(this);" onclick="customOnClick(this);submitAjax(this,'PageContainer','a_r898BB6A34E694110894F489DA4BEA3BB1DE_3','0','','','','N','',null,'');">Continue</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: The `:not()` selector only works in IE9+.

Comment: not relevant to the question, but if you're using `!important` like that, then you're almost certainly doing something wrong. `!important` should only be used as a last resort. There is almost always a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support those CSS selectors. But you're way over complicating things.

It'd be simpler using multiple selectors and you don't need to use the unsupported pseudo classes

```
UL.action{
  background: url("../images/buttons/btnShineBackground.png") top left repeat-x;
}
UL.action.btnImage{
  background: none:
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: You're using CSS features in your selectors that are not supported in IE8.

IE8 does not support CSS `:not()`. Therefore your selector won't work. And therefore none of the CSS inside that selector will be seen.

your options are:

1. Rewrite your CSS so you only use features that are available in the browsers you want to support.
2. Keep using those features, and stop supporting IE8.
3. Use a polyfill script like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to help IE8 understand those CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support that Pseudo class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support CSS3 selectors (e.g. `:not`)

Reference: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3